React dynamic form validation minimize rerendering
I have a dynamic form -- as in, a form defined by data like
[{
  id: "password",
  type: "text",
  label: "Password",
  validations: [{
    type: "required",
    valuesAt: ["password"]
  }]
},{
  id: "password-confirm",
  type: "text",
  label: "Password Confirmation",
  validations: [{
    type: "required",
    valuesAt: ["password-confirm"]
  },{
    type: "must-equal",
    valuesAt: ["password", "password-confirm"]
  }]
}]

As you can see, the validations require access to all form data, because you never know what values they may need in order to validate a particular field.
This also means that currently, whenever they type into a field, all the fields re-render to update the validation function with the new data.
Customer reports typing as "feels sluggish" at a hundred fields. I could debounce the typing to cover up the problem, but my question is: is there a way to validate against all the form data without having it re-render every time there's a change to the form data? Maybe a state library that allows for functions against state?
